# How to get current package for manifestPlaceholder?

Tags: android, gradle

I have next intent in AndroidManifest:

```
//...
<intent
     android:action="android.settings.REQUEST_IGNORE_BATTERY_OPTIMIZATIONS"
        android:data="package:${package}"
        android:targetPackage="com.android.settings"/>
//...
```

And in build.gradle:

```
android {
...
    defaultConfig {
//...
        manifestPlaceholders = [package:"ru.smart.gks"]
    }
}
```

But this dos'nt work.

How to get manifestPlaseholder for current application package if i have 2 build flavors (+ 2 build variants - debug and release)

Comment: What does *doesn't work* mean? What error are you prompt with?

Comment: @azizbekian value package in building process return null

Comment: @abbath0767 do u want to replace  replace a placeholder string in AndroidManifest.xml with productFlavor package name??

Comment: nope. depending on the flavour I have different paths to app